# Time a DB operation without data retrieval

Tags: sql

I would like to time an operation such as the following:

```
SELECT myFunc(x) FROM my100MRowTable
```

In other words, how long it takes to run that function 100M times. However, this will also include the time it takes to retrieve the data. Is there a way to do something like the following but force all rows to be evaluated?

```
SELECT myFunc(x) FROM my100MRowTable LIMIT 0
```

One thing I thought of might be to group by some constant, such as:

```
select myFunc(x) FROM my100MRowTable GROUP BY "for-testing"
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. How can you time a SQL statement if you don't want to include the part where the data is retrieved? Are you just trying to time how long it takes the engine to create a query plan? Or do you just want to determine how long it takes to call a SQL function 100 million times?

Comment: @kmoser -- just how long to call a function -- it's a UDF, and so I want to see approximately how long a function call will take.

Comment: Have a (recursive) cte that counts to 100M instead.

Comment: Is myFunc deterministic or not?

Comment: Don't forget to add a tag for the dbms used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a recursive cte to minimize overhead. Something like:

```
with recursive t(c) as
    (values(1)
     union all
     select c + 1
     from t
     fetch first 100000000 rows only)
select max(myFunc(c)) from t;
```

(And start with a smaller number, 1000000 calls took me 12 seconds.)

Comment: thanks, how do you think that approach would compare to grouping on a falsey constant like I've done in the question?